# How do I delete a desktop home screen on Nexus 7 2013?

Tags: nexus-7, home-screen, 4.3-jelly-bean

Device: Nexus 7 2013
Android: 4.3

How do I delete a desktop home screen on Nexus 7 2013? I tried everything: pinch zooming, double tap, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: What page are you talking about? Browser page?

Comment: Sorry, I meant just an empty home screen' with no icons

Comment: Try a different launcher?

Comment: Rephrased the question. This can be reopened now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had the original Nexus 7 (now dead), there was no way to delete a page from the homescreen. So, I'm not surprised the Nexus 7 v2 still doesn't have this feature.

On the original Nexus 7, I flashed the CyanogenMod ROM, which uses the Trebuchet launcher. This launcher had the feature to delete a page from the homescreen.

If flashing a new ROM is overkill, you can install a new launcher, as [t0mm13b](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/4003/t0mm13b) suggested. I personally use Nova Launcher on my Samsung Galaxy S4, which lets me delete a home screen by launching `Nova Settings` from the home screen (via left soft key), and going to `Desktop > Home Screens`.

Answer (score 1):

I've switched to [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) on my devices so that I can have more control over the layout and number of screens.

[ADW, Apex and Nova (and others)](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=launcher&c=apps) have free versions you can try. Nova will even import your current layout so you don't have to reconfigure. I think Apex may offer that option as well.